# Changing the Default Value of the Country Input type from US to "United States"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a shop based WordPress website. I am trying to change the default Input Value of country from US to United States.

```
<input id="billing_country" class="country_to_state" type="hidden" value="US" name="billing_country">
```

How can i get this?? Currently i have done it using the jQuery, the value changed but when the users proceeds for the payment its giving an error

```
Unfortunately we do not ship to United States. Please enter an alternative shipping address.
```

Comment: You should not attempt to change the value of this hidden input directly, since it is connected to woocommerce behavior. What is your goal for making the change? Is it to because you want "United States" displayed instead of "US" in some part of the UI? Perhaps there is another way to approach this. Does woocommerce allow assignment of a description / friendly name for the country list? Or do you think it is a bug in a particular area of woocommerce that is displaying the value in lieu of the county name?

Comment: The problem you're going to run into is that wooCommerce uses country ISO codes for countries and United States is not an ISO code.  You should NOT change this with jQuery for a whole bunch of reasons.  The display name for the US is already United States, I'm guessing that US is displaying somewhere you don't want it to?  You should instead attempt to change it where it is being displayed and not here since this field affects the inner workings of WooCommerce.